# Show element of array in pdf file with pdfmake

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, pdfmake

In my angular project, I arrive at the final page with an array containing data taken from a database.
How can I import them into pdf through pdfmake? I want to show a table with in first column interv.code and in the second column interv.description

```
interv: AssociationInt[]
```

```
export class AssociationInt {
    interv: Interv
    price: number
    details: string
```

```
export class Interv {
    id: number
    code: string
    description: string
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in the component.ts file.

```
const content = [
{
          table: {
            headerRows: 1,
            widths: ['auto', 'auto'],
            body: [
              ['Code', 'Description'],
              ...this.interv.map(intervObj => 
                  [intervObj.interv.code, intervObj.interv.description]
              )
            ]
          }
        }
]
```

Then, generate the PDF using pdfMake.

```
pdfMake.createPdf(content).open();
```

Comment: Nice to know. You might consider upvoting the answer if you wish.